# Fill ComboBox in UserForm with defined Range

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

In my UserForm is a ComboBox, this ComboBox shows a list with more than 100 values. If I start typing some letters into the ComboBox I want that the dropdown-list will automatically only shows the values which has the typed letters (this works fine so far). But if I choose one value the ComboBox will stay empty.

Here is my code for the ComboBox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("B1").Value = dbCustomer.Value
    dbCustomer.RowSource = "=ddCustomer"   'Named Range
End Sub
```

In my Worksheet "DataSheet" in column "D" I wrote the formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Customer;AGGREGAT(15;6;(ROW(Customer)-1)/(--(SEARCH($B$1;Customer)>0));ZEILE()-1);1);"")
```

The named range "ddCustomer" I saved with:

```
=DataSheet!$D$2:INDEX(DataSheet!$D$2:$D$105;COUNTIF(DataSheet!$D$2:$D$105;"?*"))
```

What do I have to change, that the value which I choose will shown in the ComboBox?

**EDIT**

Could find a solution, maybe it is not perfect but it works fine for me.

```
Private Sub dbCustomer_Change()

    Dim customer As Object
    Set customerValue = Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("C2:C479").Find(dbCustomer.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If customerValue Is Nothing Then
        dbCustomer.Clear
        GoTo FillDB
    Else
        Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("B1").Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

FillDB:
    Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("B1").Value = dbCustomer.Value
    For Each customer In Worksheets("DataSheet").Range("D2:D479")
        If customer <> "" Then
            dbCustomer.AddItem customer.Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is Customer in the formula?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Customer is a column in my table. i could find a solution, maybe not perfect but it works fine for me